# Consumer from Flutter provider package not updating

Tags: flutter, updates, consumer, flutter-provider

I have a Product listing where their is a `heart icon button` to mark it as favorite. using provider I am able to update the data but for the below case its not working directly.

```
Consumer<ProductProvider>(
              builder: (ctx, product, child) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  widget.product.isFavourite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                  color:
                      widget.product.isFavourite ? Colors.orange : iconColor,
                ),
                onPressed: () => setState((){
                  widget.product.isFavourite = !widget.product.isFavourite;
                }) ,
              ),
            ),
```

the above code is in my `product card widget` which is been used in `Future Builder` > `List View builder`.

if I click on the `heard Icon` in that `list view` and then navigate to that product details page. the Data is updated or that product is show to be favorite which is correct.

Now the Issue, From my `Product Details Page` if I click on the `Heart Icon` to mark that product as favorite or not favorite ( if already favorite ), then the data is updated on that page, but not in the `List View Builder` from previous page where the Product Card have the Consumer been used, unless the page is rebuild or I scroll the list view where more or other products are loaded which make the data update and then that change is reflected.

My product model is as below,

```
class ProductModel with ChangeNotifier {

  ...

  // change product favorite status. 
  void toggleIsFavourite() {
    this.isFavourite = !this.isFavourite;
    notifyListeners();
  } 
}
```

// product details page heart button code

```
actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon : Icon(
                product.isFavourite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color:
                    product.isFavourite ? red : iconColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () => setState((){
                product.toggleIsFavourite();
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

#### Test Case

1) I Click on `heart icon` in product card and not inside `heart icon` on product details page.

---

result : Everything is working.

---

2) I Click on `heart icon` in product detail page and not inside `heart icon` on product card widget which is on home page.

---

result : heart on product card on home page is not updated unless the data of the list view is refreshed or the home page is rebuild even though I am using `Consumer` to just update the value for that `heart icon` in product card.

---

Comment: You are calling `setState` and manually modifying the value inside of calling `toggleIsFavourite`. So notifyListeners is never called

Comment: Oh sorry to make it confusing. the above code given is from the product card and not product details page. product detail page code added above. @RémiRousselet

Comment: @RémiRousselet please check the update

Answer (score 4):

if you set the correct notifier above these screen, try

```
Consumer<ProductProvider>(
          builder: (ctx, product, child) => IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              product.isFavourite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              color:
                  product.isFavourite ? Colors.orange : iconColor,
            ),
            onPressed: () => 
              product.toggleIsFavourite(),
          ),
        ),
```

this way your icon gets updated based on your product provider notifications.

Make sure you can access the `isFavourite` property of your `ProductModel`.

same way with product details

```
actions: <Widget>[
      Consumer<ProductProvider>(
          builder: (ctx, product, child) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon : Icon(
                product.isFavourite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: product.isFavourite ? red : iconColor,
              ),
            onPressed: () => product.toggleIsFavourite(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
```

and you avoid changing widgets' states altogether.

this may not be 100% correct, but it has worked for me